# WHERE Clause in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

How to use WHERE clause while inserting values into the table?

I tried the below query to insert values into the column, whichever set address='COB'

```
insert into table empt (loc,country,mob)
values ('&loc','&country',&mob)
where address='COB';
```

Comment: It throws me SQL Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name" But I have the table

Comment: A `WHERE` clause is used to restrict the result set from a `SELECT`, but it doesn't make sense in the context of your `INSERT`.  Are you trying to insert values selected from another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into table empt (loc,country,mob)
select loc,country,&mob
where address='COB';
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you may need to use `update` if the field already exists in your table -

i.e.

```
update empt 
   set loc =?, country = ?, mob=? 
where address ='COB';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ltaylor

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, why you are using "Table" in insert statement.

**INSERT**

```
insert into empt (loc,country,mob)
values ('&loc','&country',&mob)
```

Hope you need Update.

**UPDATE**

```
Update empt
Set loc = '&loc',
country = '&country',
mob = &mob
where address='COB';
```

Please refer SQL Statements used in oracle

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_dml.htm#TDDDG23100

Comment: Thanks a lot Vipin :)